# Reactive java method hide()

Tags: java, android, rx-java

what is hide method in class Observable used for?
I read the document but still has no idea what it is used for and I saw lots of people use it

```
 hide()
    Hides the identity of this Observable and its Disposable.
```

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html

When should we use this method?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, you will see in the next sentence:

> Allows hiding extra features such as Subject's Observer methods or preventing certain identity-based optimizations (fusion).

An example would be:

```
PublishSubject<Object> objectPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

Observable<Object> hide = objectPublishSubject.hide();
```

Lets say, you use a PublishSubject internally and you want to pass an Observable to the outside world. This would be a good idea, because of information hiding. The caller from outside would not be able to invoke #onNext() on an Observable. So, you could just use Observable as the return value of the method and just return the PublishSubject. That would be possible, but the caller would be able to cast it and would be able to invoke #onNext() from outside.

Observable#hide create a new Observable from PublishSubject, so no casting would be possible.

Comment: Greatt!!!! By the way, if I have an Observable A onNext("A"), I want each time Observable A call onNext, an Observable B also call onNext("A"). It is like Observable A pass value to Observable B. How can I do that? For example MVVM model, View push Observable of Button click to ViewModel and ViewModel can subscribe to it. Note that ViewModel has no reference to View

Comment: Please create a new issue for this question, that others can contribute to it.

Comment: For me works fine without hide(): 
PublishSubject<Object> objectPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<Object> hide = objectPublishSubject

Comment: after calling hide i cannot call onNext() anymore, but how to restore the subject ? i dont see a subject.show() for example

Comment: @j2emanue, that's exactly the point. You want to hide the Subject from other callers, that they do not call #onNext / #accept. You most likely use #hide, when you have to fulfill a public API.